# Derivatives/Optimization, Macroeconomics-New Keynesian economy-from Heijdra book

Tags: derivatives, economics

So I get the process shown till (e).
What I do not understand is how they get from (f) to (g), and unfortunately, also from there till (j). If anyone could show me how they did the derivatives + insertion of functions into other ones, I would be really thankful!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qo4qw.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFYXR.png)

Comment: What is the definition of C (given in 11.2)? At the moment I can post an answer that shows the steps from (f) to (g). Would it be sufficient at first?

Comment: Please read my questions more carefully and answer them. Are you kidding me?

Comment: I am really sorry. I accidentally uploaded the previous photo. I just re-did it. Sorry again! 
https://imgur.com/a/VuhEFmK
https://imgur.com/a/bbIsJbR